# How to replace looping to create 1 result table from 2 other tables

Tags: python

I have 1 table with parameters as follow. I call each line a strategy:

```
Strategy    Root    Strip   Side    EntryDate   ExitDate    
0           PMI 2019-12-01  Buy     2019-11-01  2019-11-11 
1           NEP 2019-12-01  Buy     2019-11-01  2019-11-12 
...
```

Now I want to know what was the historical value of each strategy for the past 7 years. So, I loop 7 times to each strategies and each time I remove 1 year from the Strip, the Entry Date and the Exit Date. With those new parameters I query a database with all the historical prices that looks like this:

```
Date          Price
2018-11-01    40.90
2018-11-02    41.25
2018-11-05    45.00
2018-11-06    45.10
2018-11-07    44.90
2018-11-08    45.00
2018-11-09    46.10
...
```

and I get a result table that look like this showing the past 7 years of the profit for buying on entry date and selling on exit date. That Also examine every day in between to identify the highest price and the lowest price of in the holding period:

```
Id Year EntryDate   ExitDate    EntryPrice ExitPrice Profit BestDate    Best WorstDate Worst
1   2018 2018-11-01 2018-11-09  40.9       46.1      5.2    2018-11-09  5.2  2018-11-02 0.35
1   2017 2017-11-01 2017-11-10  35.55      38.2      2.65   2017-11-09  3.35 2017-11-02 0.30
```

```py
for x in range(0,1470000):
    #Here I populate variables from the strategy parameter table
    for y in range(0,7):
        #Here I modify the variables to represent each of the past seven years and then I query the prices for each of the past 7 years and populate the result table
```

Since I have 1,470,000 strategies which populate a result table of (7 years *  1,470,000 strategies) = 10,290,000 lines, it takes way too long. I estimate it would take a month to run it as it is now.

I wonder if someone can direct me to study an alternative way of solving that problem?

Comment: Have you looked into using pandas?

Comment: Yes, the dataframe I create with the loops are Pandas dataframe

Comment: No, you should make the original tables pandas dataframes, and use pands join instead of looping.

Comment: Can I join on more than one column? And can the joined column have different names?

Comment: I'm not a pandas programmer, but I can't see why you wouldn't be able to do both of those.